# can't update DB using put request in express.js

Tags: mongodb, express

I'm trying to update the languages_known through post request to the mongodb collection using the body of the request but its not updating i'm newbie any help would be really appreciated.

**mongodb document :**

```
 {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d63e81c342987154cdc698e"
      },
      "name": "anjana",
      "email": "anju@gmail.com",
      "age": "22",
      "languages_known": [
        "Bengali",
        "Kannada"
      ],
      "phone": "684684684846"
    }
```

**server code :**

```
    app.put('/students/add',function(req,res){
        var myobj={
           $set:{_id:require('mongodb').ObjectID(req.body.id),languages_known:req.body.remove}
    }


db.collection('students').updateOne({languages_known:req.body.add},myobj,function(err,result){
        if(err){throw err}
        console.log("updated")       
    })
})
```

**request body :**

```
{
  "id":"5d63e81c342987154cdc698e",
  "remove": ["Bengali", "Kannada"],
  "add": ["Tamil", "Punjabi"]
}
```

I've expected to update the languages_known field using this req through postman to this id

Comment: PUT is not POST

Comment: sorry its put not post

Comment: could u please see the code and suggest the errors to make it work

Comment: The server uses PUT, you make your request using PUT? Also, did you use `body-parser`?

Comment: Yes i've used body parser

Comment: app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

Comment: Alright, then the problem is more likely to come from your usage of mongodb, of which I'm not an expert

Comment: the data in the body of the put request is in correct format ?

Comment: @Hashimaslam : Did you test the query in DB ?

Comment: It looks correct to me

Comment: you mean in mongodb command prompt ?@srinivasy

Comment: @Hashimaslam : Anywhere how you connect to DB, either by any client like mongo compass/robo3T or at least thru mongo shell, Ok as far as I can say that query might not work !! Let me know what exactly you need I can help you with query..there are couple of issues with current query, you can not update _id of a document like that(if your actual intend is to update it)..

Comment: im using mongo shell you are correct the query is not working ,What i'm exactly want to do is i need to update the languages_known on the above collection i've posted through request in the object id i sent through request like the request body i've attached above

Comment: @Hashimaslam : So you wanted to replace the languages_known based on _id ?

Comment: @srinivasy exactly

Comment: @srinivasy  Thanks much its working now!!!

Comment: @srinivasy bro which is the best backend to learn node.js or python

Comment: @Hashimaslam : people say python is easy & trending, I'm a beginner in it & felt a bit the same, but if you've javascript experience node.js would be easy for you !! My suggestion is though it takes sometime but learn both, with some good knowledge on one language it wouldn't be of much effort to get into other at least to get hands-on, anyway realtime work is different you need to deep dive & experience would help you on the go, depends on your region what gets you job quick & your interest start with it & if you tend to learn new you can shift at anytime.. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable suggestion @srinivasy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this issue is with the query, you can't update `_id` of a document like that, also as your requirement is not to do that, Please try this :

**server code :**

```
// replace languages_known with new languages based on _id, in case if you wanted to update the array you can use $push
app.put('/students/add', function (req, res) {

const id = require('mongodb').ObjectID(req.body.id)
    let updateQuery = {
        $set: { languages_known: req.body.add }
    }


    db.collection('students').updateOne({ _id: id }, updateQuery, function (err, result) {
        if (err) { throw err }
        console.log("updated")
    })
})
```